# CUDA ERROR: initialization error when using parallel in python

Tags: python, cuda, parallel-processing

I use CUDA for my code, but it still slow run. Therefore I change it to run parallel using multiprocessing (pool.map) in python. But I have `CUDA ERROR: initialization error`

This Is function :

```
def step_M(self, iter_training):
    gpe, e_tuple_list = iter_training
    g = gpe[0]
    p = gpe[1]
    em_iters = gpe[2]

    e_tuple_list = sorted(e_tuple_list, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    data = self.X[e_tuple_list[0][0]:e_tuple_list[0][1]]
    cluster_indices = np.array(range(e_tuple_list[0][0], e_tuple_list[0][1], 1), dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(1, len(e_tuple_list)):
        d = e_tuple_list[i]
        cluster_indices = np.concatenate((cluster_indices, np.array(range(d[0], d[1], 1), dtype=np.int32)))
        data = np.concatenate((data, self.X[d[0]:d[1]]))

    g.train_on_subset(self.X, cluster_indices, max_em_iters=em_iters)
    return g, cluster_indices, data
```

And here code call:

```
pool = Pool()
iter_bic_list = pool.map(self.step_M, iter_training.items())
```

The iter_training same:
[image]

And this is errors
[image]
could you help me to fix.Thanks you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. the cause of libcudart is set path lib. 
I set :
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so /usr/lib/libcudart.so
sudo ldconfig. then it not show error it. BUt CUDA EROROR: initialization still show

Answer (score 8):

I found this is a problem with cuda putting a mutex for a process ID.
So when you use the multiprocessing module another subprocess with a separate pid is spawned. And it is not able to access because of the mutex for the GPU.

A quick solution which I found to be working is using the threading module instead of the multiprocessing module.

So basically the same pid which loads the network in the gpu should use it.

Comment: This has helped me five years later with tensorflow 2.6.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had gone through the same problem, reason behind this is If you create a CUDA context before the **fork()**, you cannot use that within the child process. The **cudaSetDevice(0)**; call attempts to share the CUDA context, implicitly created in the parent process when you call **cudaGetDeviceCount();**.
**Solution:**

Two possible solutions for the above problem:-

1-Either all Cuda related operation should be performed under parent or child process(*Make sure no Cuda call make in parent process if operation under child process* like torch.cuda.is_available() and torch.manual_seed both count as a CUDA calls in PyTorch 0.2.0.)

2-Change Process type to **spawn()** for python use syntax *multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')* before initaialzing process

e.g :

```
import multiprocess as multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun, args=(param1,)
p1.start()
p1.join()
```

Comment: Can I plus 100 for #2. This saved me so hard.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a bit old but I ran into the same problem, while running under celery in my case:

```
syncedmem.cpp:63] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (3 vs. 0)  initialization error
```

Switching from prefork to an eventlet based pool has resolved the issue.  Your code could be updated similarly to:

```
from eventlet import GreenPool
pool = GreenPool()
iter_bic_list = list(pool.imap(self.step_M, iter_training.items()))
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am not using Pool but a multiprocessing.Process what should I do?

Comment: This is sequential..

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Comment: The command ldconfig is fix libcudart. because It not see path. Could you help me fix the CUDA ERROR: initialization error.

Comment: Could you try going into NVIDIA_samples/1_utilities/deviceQuery and run. /deviceQuery? What do you see?