# My function works fine by itself but not when I run it as a worker

Tags: python, multiprocessing, yolo

I am trying to run multiple Yolos in parallel in Python.

I have a function that I am trying to use as the worker. something like this:

```
import darknet as dn
def yolo(input_queue, net, meta):
    while True:
        task = input_queue.get_nowait()
        c = task.shape[0]
        h = task.shape[1]
        w = task.shape[2]
        task = (task/255.0)
        task = task.flatten()
        new_arr = np.copy(task).astype(np.float32) 
        new_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(new_arr)
        im = dn.IMAGE(w,h,c,new_arr)
        dn.rgbgr_image(im)

        print(dn.detect(net, meta, im))
```

You can find darknet file [here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/python/darknet.py).

Let's don't talk about the way I convert the array to a ctype array. it has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755064/what-is-the-fastest-way-of-converting-a-numpy-array-to-a-ctype-array).

If I run this function as a normal function works like a charm. But if I run it as a worker like this:

```
p = Process(target=yolo, args=(input_queue, net, meta))
p.start()
```

it goes all the way down to the last line then it gives me this error:

```
CUDA Error: initialization error
python: ./src/cuda.c:36: check_error: Assertion `0' failed.
```

I couldn't figure out why exactly this error happens.
can anyone help?  what's the difference between these two way of using this function that cause this problem?

Comment: [Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748750/cuda-error-initialization-error-when-using-parallel-in-python)

Comment: You may may need to put the "entry point" of the main script within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` conditional as described in the "Safe importing of main module" section of the `multiprocessing` **Programming guidelines** [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

Comment: @GeeTransit it is different but answer by sagarwal gave me the idea to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083505/6701576) I found the problem is that you can't share the context in CUDA between processes with different PIDs which makes sense. So I found that if I run related things (in my case, `net`) in the same process then it works okay. before this I was loading weights before I start the worker.